# Django API "request count" now showing in Azure App Insights > Performance with opencensus

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-application-insights, opencensus

running into an issue where my Django python API application is not logging all metrics to Azure App Insights using [opencensus](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure).

[image: request count]

But for example, we are getting CPU/memory logging:
[image: cpu]

I would expect the performance > request count to look similar to this (on a different application framework):
[image: working app request count]

The [performance counters](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure#performance-counters) section looks pretty straight forward.

My code looks like this:

```py
from opencensus.ext.azure import metrics_exporter

def main():
  INSTRUMENTATION_KEY = os.getenv("INSTRUMENTATION_KEY", "xxx")

  exporter = metrics_exporter.new_metrics_exporter(connection_string='InstrumentationKey='+INSTRUMENTATION_KEY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make sure if your app's requests have been captured and you may refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#telemetry-type-mappings), `Incoming requests, outgoing requests <=> Tracing`

Hence, according to the tutorial you provided, I'm new to python, but I assume that you may consider [this section](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure#integrations)?

Comment: this was helpful - thank you for clarifying my misunderstanding! After adding the tracing, we see what we are looking for.

Comment: @Soccerjoshj07 Thanks for your reply and I'm glad to see it worked for you : )